# Remove last two digits of number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a number that comes from an external API but it has two extra zeros at the end. What would be a solution to remove the two zeros. I have tried the `chomp` method and that doesn't work.  The number I receive from the API is a `Bignum`. I am using Ruby 2.

This is a sample input from the API is `1374577200000`

This is a sample output I want is `13745772000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't chomp a Fixnum or Bignum, so you'd have to convert it back and forth:

```
number = 123400
number.to_s[0..-3].to_i
```

Comment: `[0...-2]` may be a little bit clearer, even though it does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 12):

If the number is an integer, you can use integer division:

```
> 123456 / 100
=> 1234
```

Comment: Or if not an integer `123456.to_i / 100`